# Mining Fee for the blocks that are stale

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, mining

This question is regarding the blockchain and bitcoin. Suppose a miner mined a block and the block got added in the main chain of the block chain. He must have got his mining fee then. Now suppose that due to a fork sometimes later, the block that he mined is no longer a part of the main chain, i.e. that block is orphaned now. Then would he retain his mining fee or would it get deducted?

Comment: Would this more suited for the [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Posted there too!

Answer (score -1):

As I understood the forks of the blockchain, every fees you got and any money you have gets converted to the new money... So you will still have your money but converted to the new type of money. So instead of having a bitcoin you may then have like 20 bitcoins which are worth the same in dollars. So your mined block is not any longer in the blockchain as it was before but after the fork your money is still there as there are new blocks from the fork which confirm that you have the money...

Hope you understood what I wanted to say.
I'm not English so forgive me if my English is a bit sluggish from time to time.